# ADF, data conversion in 'copy data'

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have data from JSON API that keep in the staging table before it move to destination table. Data type of destination columns are `datetime` and the source columns in the staging table are varchar(512). I got error when debugging because of datatype conversion between varchar (512) to datetime. This below message is the error message:

> ErrorCode=TypeConversionFailure,Exception occurred when converting
> value '2021-09-16T07:58:39.187+07:00' for column name 'start__date'
> from type 'String' (precision:255, scale:255) to type 'DateTime'
> (precision:23, scale:3). Additional info: String was not recognized as
> a valid DateTime.

I tried in SSMS:

```
declare @This_time  varchar(256) = '2021-09-16T07:58:39.187+07:00'
    , @MyTime datetime

set @MyTime = Cast(@This_time   as datetime)
select @MyTime
```

and the error message

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 7 Conversion failed when converting
> date and/or time from character string.
>
> Completion time: 2021-11-02T20:51:31.5345885+07:00

It looks `completion time` and value from staging table have same pattern. I tried once again with
`datetime2` in SSMS and it works. This is the result `2021-09-16 07:58:39.187`

I assume the data type is default but it can be changed. First attempt and error.
[image]

Then, I changed the format in the JSON `Code` became `datetime2`. Second attempt still no luck.
[image]

This is my destination table

[image]

how to solve this data conversion in ADF, `copy data` ?

Answer (score 0):

The datatype that you are trying to cast is actually *datetimeoffset*, see [the MSFT docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#DateandTimeDataTypes). See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=68407507ff9e797c32137ab09b0935c4) for a working example.